Sequelize association based on jsonb attribute
A bit contrived, but for simplicity let's say I have a Post model+table with a JSONB column details, and in details there is a userId.
Is there a way in Sequelize to setup an association using this?
I've tried doing:
Post.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'details->userId', as: 'user'});

but of course I get error:
error: column "details->userId" does not exist

And yes, I realize a proper foreign key would be better here.

postgres doesn't have direct FK association from JSONB, so I would say this is not possible in Sequelize.  You probably need to add a column for the userId with a setter. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489647/json-foreign-keys-in-postgresql

I don't need it to be an actual association in the database; just the ability to eager load in Sequelize.

If you don't make Sequelize association, you won't be able to use Sequelize include.  You probably need to write raw join query with Sequelize.literal.

Right yeah - the question is about how to make such an association in Sequelize.
The main reason it'd be nice is because I have some existing sequelize code which already doing a lot of nested includes, but now I need another based on field in a JOSNB column... so it's a PITA to have to switch the whole thing to a raw query.
I suspect sequelize doesn't have a way to handle this, so this post is more posterity's sake.

Ah. I forgot about this but you can use Sequelize.literal for include: { association: model, on: Sequelize.literal() }. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11788#issuecomment-1012287531
you can try writing the custom JSONB connection in the literal.

Oh interesting. I was able to get it to produce the query I wanted by doing on: sequelize.literal(\("Post".details->>'userId')::UUID = "user".id`)in the include. However, that doesn't work without definingPost.belongsTo(User), and that doesn't work without a foreignKey to point it to. So in order to get the query to work at all I could add an unused column just to make the belongsTo` happy, but... that's pretty janky.
